# RecyclerView Vertical scroll bar is not visible in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, wear-os

I have ViewPager with 2 tabs:

1. any content (visible tab)
2. list content in RecyclerView (I use WearableRecyclerView for WearOS project but I think it doesn't matter)

When I swipe to tab with RecyclerView i don't see scroll bar.

Both methods is not work for me:

- `android:scrollbars="vertical"`
- `recyclerview.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true`
- `recyclerview.isScrollbarFadingEnabled = false`

Has anyone had a similar problem with a RecyclerView Scroll Bar in a ViewPager?

Comment: Also, share your RecyclerView code

Comment: #wearos I am having the same problem now, scrollbar is visible only if recycler view is placed to first (default) tab of the view pager, which is visible when view pager is created